# PHP - return to another page using header

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to update data in database using oop php but after I call function update I should return the user to view all page , so i used header but then whenever i try to view update page, it views view all page.
what should i do?

```
<body>

    <form  method='POST'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='id' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>price</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='price' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type='submit' name='commit' value='Submit'>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>

<?php
require_once ('database.php');
require_once ('admin.php');
$object= new admin();
if (isset($_POST['commit'])) {
$id    = $object->clean($_POST['id']);
$price = $object->clean($_POST['price']);
$object->update_sport($id ,$price);
}
header("C:\wamp\www\omnia\viewsports.php");
```

this is viewsports.php

```
<head>
        <title>Sports</title>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1>Sports</h1>
         <h3>Use ID to update</h3>
        <?php 
        require_once 'database.php';
        $obj=new databaseClass();
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr bgcolor="white">';
        echo ' <td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td>';
        echo ' </tr>';
        $sql="SELECT sport.id, sport.name, sport.price FROM sport";

        $result=  mysql_query($sql);
        $i=0;
        while($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo  '<tr><td>' .$row['id'].'</td><td>'
            .$row['name'].'</td><td>'
            .$row['price'].'</td>'
            .'<td><a href="delete_sport.php?id=' . $row['id'].'">Delete</a></td>'
            .'<td><a href="update_sport.php?id=' . $row['id'].'">Update</a></td></tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        echo'</table>';
        ?>
         <a href="add_sport.php">Add</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

```
class admin{

public function clean($str) {
        $str = trim($str); // remove 
                /*Magic Quotes, generally speaking, is the process of escaping special characters with a '\' to allow a string to be entered into a database. This is considered 'magic' because PHP can do this automatically for you if you have magic_quotes_gpc turned on.

More specifically if magic_quotes_gpc is turned on for the copy of PHP you are using all Get, Post & Cookie variables (gpc, get it?) in PHP will already have special characters like ", ' and \ escaped so it is safe to put them directly into an SQL query.*/

                if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
```

Comment: I think this needs a bit more clarification. What page is it you're showing? What is viewsports.php?

Comment: header('localhost/omnia/viewsports.php')

Comment: @BrockB. viewsport.php to view all sports in database.

Comment: @saty that doesn't work too!

Comment: @SarahMohamed what is this page that you've posted the code for? What is your intended result? This question is not clear enough for us to answer exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay this is viewsports.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that you are doing your redirect before you can display the update page. You want to only do the redirect if you've updated the sport.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  require_once ('database.php');
  require_once ('admin.php');
  $object= new admin();
  if (isset($_POST['commit'])) {
        $id    = $object->clean($_POST['id']);
        $price = $object->clean($_POST['price']);
        $object->update_sport($id ,$price);
        header("Location: viewsports.php");
        exit();
   }
 ?>
```

Edit:

Try this method:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  require_once ('database.php');
  require_once ('admin.php');
  $object= new admin();
  if (isset($_POST['commit'])) {
        $id    = $object->clean($_POST['id']);
        $price = $object->clean($_POST['price']);
        $object->update_sport($id ,$price);
        echo '<script>window.location = "viewsports.php";</script>';
        exit();
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: I tried this but after updating data it still in update page!

Comment: Move this code from the bottom of your page to the top of your page, and I've also made a change to the code to include an exit.

Comment: i made the changes but after updating data it didn't show anything , just a blank page

Comment: I've added another edit using a javascript method to see if that will make the redirect work.

Comment: Also, it might be worth adding this: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ` to the top of the PHP code to see if any errors are being reported.

Comment: it gives me an error in the parent class in function :    `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Where are you using that method? Is it in your update function?

Comment: Nope i am using it in the parent class i will edit my question now to let you see it.

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\omnia\admin.php

Comment: I thought so - that is a warning because you're using the old mysq_* functions rather than using the more secure [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) methods. I don't believe this should effect the use of the application currently, though.

Answer (score 0):

`header` sends header informations, if you want to redirect the browser to another page, you need to use:

```
header("Location: viewsports.php"); // viewsports.php relative path
```

See PHP Manual for [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

As stated in the comments, here is another approach on how to do this (imho the better solution):

```
<?php
    require_once ('database.php');
    require_once ('admin.php');
    $object= new admin();
    if (isset($_POST['commit'])) {
        $id    = $object->clean($_POST['id']);
        $price = $object->clean($_POST['price']);
        $object->update_sport($id ,$price);
        header("Location: viewsports.php");
    } else {
?>
        <body>

            <form  method='POST'>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='id' value='' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='price' value='' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input type='submit' name='commit' value='Submit'>
        </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        </form> 
        </body>
        </html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

As you see, around the HTML stuff is the else clause, which will only be sent to the client, when data is NOT commited, if data is commited client will be redirected.

Comment: He'll get a warning, to be more specific: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line someline`

Comment: and it is better to put `exit();` after this header

Comment: I would do that using a complete different attempt. Either reload the page using JavaScript or do the stuff BEFORE the page is sent using an if-then-else clause, display the page in the else clause, if no commit data is there.

Comment: @Nidhoegger i didn't understand this!

Comment: If clauses can be also used on plain HTML. Ill post an example in a Minute. See edit.

Comment: He wants a redirect, not an include.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should like below

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  require_once ('database.php');
  require_once ('admin.php');
  $object= new admin();
  if (isset($_POST['commit'])) {
         $id    = $object->clean($_POST['id']);
        $price = $object->clean($_POST['price']);
        $object->update_sport($id ,$price);
 }
 header("location:viewsports.php");
 ?>
<body>

<form  method='POST'>
<table>


<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='id' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>price</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='price' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type='submit' name='commit' value='Submit'>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```